# how to print inside a def function

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have this program:

```
games = ['tlou', 'hitman', 'rainbow 6', 'nba2k']
print(games)
def list_o_matic(inp):
    if inp == "":
        games.pop()
        return "the game" + inp + "was deleted"
    elif inp in games:
        games.remove(inp)
        return "the game" + inp + "was removed"
    elif inp != games:
        games.append(inp)
        return "the game" + inp + "was added"
while True:
    if not games:
        print("goodbye!")
        break
    else:
        inp = input("write the name of the game: ")
        if inp == 'quit':
            print("goodbye!")
            break
        else:
            list_o_matic(inp)
            print(games)
```

what it does that you write a name(this case a video game name) and it checks if its in the list and than if not it add it if it is so the program deletes it.
the problem is the output is without the messeges that in the function and i have no clue why.

Comment: You return the message strings but you throw away the return value on your `list_o_matic(inp)` call. You need something like `print(list_o_matic(inp))`.

Comment: You are only calling `list_o_matic(inp)`, without doing a `echo`

Comment: Line 10: should be `elif inp not in games:`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are returning the message from `list_o_matic`, you should just print the returning value from the caller:

```
games = ['tlou', 'hitman', 'rainbow 6', 'nba2k']
print(games)
def list_o_matic(inp):
    if inp == "":
        games.pop()
        return "the game " + inp + " was deleted"
    elif inp in games:
        games.remove(inp)
        return "the game " + inp + " was removed"
    elif inp != games:
        games.append(inp)
        return "the game " + inp + " was added"
while True:
    if not games:
        print("goodbye!")
        break
    else:
        inp = input("write the name of the game: ")
        if inp == 'quit':
            print("goodbye!")
            break
        else:
            print(list_o_matic(inp))
            print(games)
```

Or, if you prefer to print the message inside the function as your title suggests, then print the message without returning it:

```
games = ['tlou', 'hitman', 'rainbow 6', 'nba2k']
print(games)
def list_o_matic(inp):
    if inp == "":
        games.pop()
        print("the game " + inp + " was deleted")
    elif inp in games:
        games.remove(inp)
        print("the game " + inp + " was removed")
    elif inp != games:
        games.append(inp)
        print("the game " + inp + " was added")
while True:
    if not games:
        print("goodbye!")
        break
    else:
        inp = input("write the name of the game: ")
        if inp == 'quit':
            print("goodbye!")
            break
        else:
            list_o_matic(inp)
            print(games)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify in your code `print(list_o_matic(inp))` because your function is returning a string already.